# is there any java script web crawler framework

Tags: javascript, web-crawler

Is there any JavaScript web crawler framework?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Are you looking for a web crawler implemented in JavaScript? Server-side (Node.js) or client-side (in a browser)?

Comment: Is there a client-side webcrawler framework? How would that work?

Comment: I wrote three APIs using server-side javascript. You can run `nodejs` from your command-line as easy as you can `python`. This is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 10):

There's a new framework that was just release for Node.js called [spider](https://github.com/mikeal/spider). It uses jQuery under the hood to crawl/index a website's HTML pages. The API and configuration are really nice especially if you already know jQuery.

From the test suite, here's an example of crawling the New York Times website:

```
var spider = require('../main');

spider()
  .route('www.nytimes.com', '/pages/dining/index.html', function (window, $) {
    $('a').spider();
  })
  .route('travel.nytimes.com', '*', function (window, $) {
    $('a').spider();
    if (this.fromCache) return;

    var article = { title: $('nyt_headline').text(), articleBody: '', photos: [] }
    article.body = '' 
    $('div.articleBody').each(function () {
      article.body += this.outerHTML;
    })
    $('div#abColumn img').each(function () {
      var p = $(this).attr('src');
      if (p.indexOf('ADS') === -1) {
        article.photos.push(p);
      }
    })
    console.log(article);
  })
  .route('dinersjournal.blogs.nytimes.com', '*', function (window, $) {
    var article = {title: $('h1.entry-title').text()}
    console.log($('div.entry-content').html())
  })
  .get('http://www.nytimes.com/pages/dining/index.html')
  .log('info')
  ;
```

Comment: Spend a morning to make spider to work, it can't be run in latest 0.6.6 node.js.

Comment: This is a good start, but it doesn't seem to handle meta redirects or document base overrides so it will fail to crawl many sites.  But it is the best implementation I've seen for node.  And with support for cookies it's better than other open source crawlers.

Answer (score 8):

Try the [PhantomJS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/). Not exactly a crawler, but could be easily used for that purpose. It has the fully-functional WebKit engine built-in, with an ability to save screenshots etc. Works as the simple command-line JS interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Server-side?

Try node-crawler: https://github.com/joshfire/node-crawler

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a crawler since it doesn't compile subsequent uri's to crawl.  It will basically download the source of a given URL and trigger a callback on completion.  It's up to the consumer to define logic for crawling the links provided in that page, something that isn't very straightforward.