# Web scraper that handles JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, web-scraping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make a JavaScript-aware Crawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326301/make-a-javascript-aware-crawler)

I'm trying to figure out what to use as the basis for a PHP based web scraper that can handle pages that render using JavaScript. Many web site scrape attempts (at least the ones I handle) now fail unless the JS in those pages is executed. The pages are not built to gracefully fall back to no-script implementations. This includes those that make heavy use of AJAX.

Would anyone have suggestions for where to start with the development of a web scraper that can handle modern and heavily JavaScript dependent web pages?

Something that can be used by PHP would be best.

Comment: what page are you scraping? for what content?

Comment: You can't scrape a JS page with PHP

Comment: @Dragon A lot of different pages with a lot of different content. Some sites won't function at all without JS. Sorry to sound vague. Some of it is private work for clients.

Comment: @Paul I'm looking for an option that can fetch the page, render anything needed by JS in that page's code, then give the contents to a PHP script to handle the rest. Or something similar to this. Trying to workout my options. The idea of building a JS scraper that works as a Firefox plugin had crossed by mind, but I feel there should be a more elegant solution.

Comment: well thanks for that great response, no free help for you!

Comment: @Dragon I'd give an example if I could, but I can't think of any that I'm specifically working on that I can share right now. Generally, any site that embeds JS and won't work if you turn JS off in the browser.

Comment: @dm03514 Mink looks promising! Will check it out. Thanks! :)

Comment: scrappers have a bad reputation, usually doing illegal or at least things against the sites terms and condition, stealing content etc, so that's why i ask.

Comment: @Dragon Nothing illegal or illicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to use a web browser engine in headless mode to load the page and analyze the DOM. Some googling pointed me at http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: This might work well using [pjscrape](http://nrabinowitz.github.com/pjscrape/) with a PHP url to call using jQuery to process the scraped results to a database.

Answer (score 1):

Those sites that have heavy ajax usage, just call the same urls as the page does, and build your site content on that response rather than requesting the page.

Those sites that have heavy document.write or framework equivalent thereof, you could probably just strip space or match tags or relevant content using simple regex and again request the script responsible rather than the page that requests it ...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) which is a browser automation tool and then use one of the PHP bindings [here](https://github.com/chibimagic/WebDriver-PHP/), [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver), [or here](http://code.google.com/p/php-webdriver-bindings/) so you can automate Selenium from PHP.

Comment: Selenium looks pretty useful. Could be very helpful with some other applications I have in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have a JavaScript engine in PHP. Or some headless Webkit on the command line. And even then it would get hugely complicated. So the short answer would be: No, sorry, you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

PHP supports the V8 engine, so I guess you could pass over javascript to V8. Not a pretty thing to do though, I would use something else than straight PHP to do this.